# SQL query , retrieve data based on two values

Tags: sql

I need to create a query in which I have three inputs: name, last name and city.

When the user inputs just the name, the code should show all users with the given name. If the user inputs name and city, the code should show all people with given name from that given city.

In my current case, my code doesn't show people with the given name that are form the given city, but instead all people with the given name regardless of the city. Can somebody give me some reference?

This is my code:

```
String filterQuery = "FROM Workers WHERE name='" + name + "'OR last_name='" + last_name + "'AND city='" + city + "'";
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 String filterQuery = "FROM Workers WHERE name like '%" + name + "%'and last_name like'%" + last_name + "%'AND city like'%" + city + "%'";
```

This negates the need for an OR

Comment: This approach does the work.I wasn't using LIKE clause that much and it never crossed my mind to use it here.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your query:

```
select * from Workers
where
(
ISNLL(@name ,'') <>'' and name = @name
)
AND
(ISNLL(@lastname ,'') <>'' and LastName = @Lastname)
AND
(ISNLL(@city ,'') <>'' and city = @city)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems with using an approach like this - not least the usual [well documented](https://xkcd.com/327/) SQL injection attack exploits.

But, that aside, you need to wrap your logical statements in some parentheses so as to apply the AND properly.

e.g.

```
String filterQuery = "FROM Workers WHERE (name='" + name + "'OR last_name='" + last_name + "')AND city='" + city + "'";
```

Otherwise, you've got a "floating" OR, which is likely to be interpreted differently to how you're expecting.

There's still the problem of changing the form of your query depending on how many of the three optional query parameters you're provided with but given 3 possible inputs that's only 7 possible scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Add brackets (before name= and a closing bracket before AND city)

Answer (score 0):

You need logic that will omit a condition if it isn't specified. This is done by specifying that a parameter has either the entered value or is null. If your parameters are empty strings instead of nulls, you can switch `@param IS NULL` to `@param = ''`.

```
SELECT 
  ...
FROM workers
WHERE
    ( name      = @param  OR @param  IS NULL )
AND ( last_name = @param2 OR @param2 IS NULL )
AND ( city      = @param3 OR @param3 IS NULL )
```

Just replace `@param` placeholders in above script with your input values and store that.

---

I would watch out for SQL injection though, since you are putting input values directly into the string that then you probably execute. Look into query parametrization and preparing statements before executing them directly in the database.

Comment: This might sound like a stupid question.Can you give me a reference to some good tutorials on this two subjects

Comment: There are no stupid questions but there are no specific tutorials to this subject since this isn't a big subject on it's own. It's an approach and there is nothing more to it than what I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the brackets as shown below. This should help.

String filterQuery = "FROM Workers WHERE (name='" + name + "') OR (last_name='" + last_name + "'AND city='" + city + ")'";

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Workers 
where 
(name=@name or @name='') and 
(last_name=@last_name or @last_name='') and
(city=@city or @city='')
```

answer is in MSSQL format. I hope you will format it it c#. Please let me know if any help required for that